# Maximum and minimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(\rho)=(1+v\rho)\{(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2\rho})^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}}-1\},$ where $\rho \in (0,1]$. 
Is it possible to obtain the global supremum and infimum of this function?

Hints: First, we can proceed using the necessary condition for extrema. But then we can determine the overall increasing and decreasing behaviour of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(\rho)=(1+v\rho)\left(\left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}}-1\right),$$ where $\rho \in (0,1]$.

Since $\rho \in (0,1]$, then $0 < \rho \leq 1$.

Consequently:

$$1 < (1 + v\rho) \leq 1 + v$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} \leq \left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} < \left(\frac{1}{n_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} - 1 \leq \left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} - 1 < \left(\frac{1}{n_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} - 1$$

Therefore:

$$\left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} - 1 < f(\rho) < (1 + v)\left(\left(\frac{1}{n_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}} - 1\right).$$

Comment: This will give only upper and lower bounds however how can I determine the Supremum and Infimum?